# Can primary tabs appear at the top when using Xamarin.Forms Shell

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

Client would like for primary tabs to appear on the bottom for iOS and at the top for Android.  Is this possible when using Shell?  I know nested/secondary tabs can appear at the top but again I'm referring to the primary/top-level tabs.  Does Shell force primary tabs to always be bottom tabs or is there a way to display them on top also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry , Shell force primary tabs to always be bottom , it can not be modified by us .

The layout of shell tabbar be designed as default . You can have a look at the [source code of Shell](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/ShellContentFragment.cs) here :

```
public override AView OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        if (_shellContent != null)
        {
            _page = ((IShellContentController)_shellContent).GetOrCreateContent();
        }

        _root = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ShellContent, null).JavaCast<CoordinatorLayout>();

       //here layout be designed as default 
        _toolbar = _root.FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.shellcontent_toolbar);

        _renderer = Platform.CreateRenderer(_page, Context);
        Platform.SetRenderer(_page, _renderer);

         ...

        return _root;
    }
```

Last as your said , recommand not using Shell to achieve that is possible .